# Strange results with nested handlebar blocks in Meteor

Tags: nested, meteor, handlebars.js

I am trying to set default value in an html select, but without sucess.
I'm doing the initial populating like this:

```
<template name="demo">
    <select>
        {{#each foo}}
            <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

And i set the possible options in the model like this:

```
Template.demo.foo = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
```

So far, everything work as intended.

Now i'm trying to display row of the collection collec, populating the select with the defaut recorded foo value (aaa or bbb or ccc).
My understanding is that you must add "selected" to the  tag.
So i do something like this with multiple nested blocks:

```
<template name="demo">
    {{#each collecs}}
        {{_id}}
        <select>
            {{#each foos}}
                <option{{#if isSelected this ../this}}selected{{/if}}>{{this}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And on the model front:

```
Template.demo.foos = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];

    Template.demo.collecs = function(){
      return Collec.find({});
      };

    Template.demo.isSelected = function(fooToCheck, record){
      var rid= record._id; 
      var currentRecord = Collec.findOne({_id:rid});
      return (fooToCheck==currentRecord.foo);
  };
```

The problem is that it does not work.
The dropdown stays empty, and the generated html code show something like this:

```
"              >aaa             "
```

I have checked in the js part, all seems to work correctly, true/false are adequately returned.

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars conditionals don't do well inline. In fact, I'm not sure if they work inline anywhere. What was happening was that the Handlebars templating engine didn't understand your html, so it skipped over it, which is why you saw '>aaa'.

The following code works. I took the liberty of simplifying your isSelected function.

**Template:**

```
<template name="demo">
    {{#each collecs}}
        {{_id}}
        <select>
            {{#each foos}}
                {{#if isSelected this ../foo}}
                  <option selected>{{this}}</option>
                {{else}}
                  <option>{{this}}</option>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  Template.demo.foos = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];

  Template.demo.collecs = function(){
    return Collec.find({});
  };

  Template.demo.isSelected = function(fooToCheck, recordFoo){
    return (fooToCheck === recordFoo);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try that.
I have already made inline handlebar work somewhere else, although probably not mixed with html like that, so i had no idea this could be the cause of the problem.
Thank you !

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept the answer if it works. If you still have a problem, let me know!